# In cake php , How we can access value from the database inside foreach loop?

Tags: cakephp

I am having one table 
menu with field 
id and name
1 suriya
2 kamal
3 ram

I want to retrive these value inside foreach loop in below order
1) kamal
2) suriya
3) ram

I am beginner in cake php.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty vague question, but this should get you started. Put this code in your menu's controller.

```
$menus = $this->Menu->find('all');
foreach ($menus as $menu) {
    echo $menu['Menu']['name'];
}
```

Regarding the order, if you're not ordering alphabetically, then you'll need to add a new column to your table, such as `sort_order`, and order that when you call `$this->Menu->find('all')`

Answer (score 0):

create a model named Menu.php in app/models folder -

```
class Menu extends AppModel {
      public $primaryKey = 'id';
      public $useTable = 'menu';
}
```

And create a controller named MenuController.php in app/controller folder -

```
class MenuController extends AppController {
      public $use = false;

      public function index () {

          $this->loadModel ('Menu');
          $data = $this->Menu->find ('all', array ('order' => 'name ASC'));

          foreach ($data as $value) {
                echo $value['Menu']['name'] . "<br/>";
          }
          exit;
      }
}
```

Then try it, could work. :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I achieve it by the following way.$menu= $this->requestAction('Menus/index');
$requiredMenu = array(0,4,3,5,6);

foreach($requiredMenu as $index){
   echo $this->Html->link($menu[$index]['Menu']['name'],array('controller' => $menu[$index]['Menu']['controller'],
             'action' => $menu[$index]['Menu']['action'],
             'admin' => false,
             'plugin' => false),array('class'=>'menuForFooter'));
   echo "<br>";
   
}